# Flutter hide random characters of word

Tags: flutter

I'm building an app about finding words,

I have a screen shows word and description and i want to hide some characters of word.

like A*rpl**e

is there a easier way than split to characters and pick random letters and replace with star(*)

Comment: I think you can do a for loop that loops through the variable, and on each letter get a random boolean to replace that character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jonathan Ixcayau mentions, you can use a for loop like so:

```
import 'dart:math';

String censor(String original) {
  String newValue = '';
  for (int i=0; i<original.length; i++) {
    newValue += Random().nextBool()?original[i]:'*';
  }
  return newValue;
}
```

You can also do this using some chained functions:

```
import 'dart:math';

String censor(String value) =>
  original.split('').map((v) => Random().nextBool()?v:'*').join();
```

Comment: thank you for your help :) i just want to know is there any plugin does this job im already censoring my words with function like yours

Comment: I see, sorry, I don't know of any plugin that does this...